# Round the kdb datetime to the nearest even second

Tags: kdb

I'm new in kdb q. I'm trying to round the kdb datetime to the nearest even second.

For example, for the table below:

```
tp_time   price     synp
------------------------
05:00:03  1697.15   1697.15
05:00:05  1697.15   1697.15
...
```

And my expected table is the following:

```
tp_time   price     synp
------------------------
05:00:02  1697.15   1697.15
05:00:04  1697.15   1697.15
...
```

Could someone gives me some hints about this question?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tp_time` type in the question asked is `second` (`v`) so the `2 xbar tp_time` will work nicely; however, if the `tp_time` is of type `time`(`t`) or `timespan`(`n`) then the following will generate the correct results regardless of the datatype.

```
q)t:([] tp_time:05:00:03.123 05:00:05.345 ; price:1697.15  1697.15; synp:1697.15  1697.15) //check out the meta of the table

q)update tp_time:2 xbar tp_time.second from t    //usinng tp_time.second
tp_time  price   synp
------------------------
05:00:02 1697.15 1697.15
05:00:04 1697.15 1697.15
```

Here we are accessing the `second` constituent of `tp_time` (`tp_time.second`).

Answer (score 4):

A related point to Jonathons, if your timestamps are of type "timespan" (aka type 16h) then you can specify the "2" as 0D00:00:02 as follows

```
q)0D00:00:02 xbar 0D05:00:03 0D05:00:04 0D05:00:05 0D05:00:06
0D05:00:02.000000000 0D05:00:04.000000000 0D05:00:04.000000000 0D05:00:06.000000
000
```

This can make the code easier to follow, especially if you start getting into different levels of granularity of the buckets.

Note - you can see this built-in handling for type 16 in the xbar function

```
q)xbar
k){x*y div x:$[16h=abs[@x];"j"$x;x]}
```

Outside of timespans you can also make it easier to read for other datatypes by casting the timebucket to long

```
q)("j"$00:02) xbar 05:00:02 05:00:03 05:00:04
05:00:02 05:00:02 05:00:04
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `xbar`

```
q)2 xbar 05:00:03 05:00:05
05:00:02 05:00:04
```

So in your case it'd be something like `update 2 xbar tp_time from t`