# How do I round a datetime to the nearest minute in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have an array of timestamps of the form:

```
2022.05.23T14:31:04.222
```

I'm trying to round them to the nearest date-minute, such that the output would be `2022.05.23T14:31:00.000`.

I've various casts (e.g. `minute$t), and also `00:01:00 xbar t`, but none of these worked.

How should it be done?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070595/round-the-kdb-datetime-to-the-nearest-even-second) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Don't use `datetime` datatype (aka .z.Z, aka type 15, aka "z"$) use `timestamp` datatype (aka .z.P, aka type 12, aka "p"$). The former is underpinned by a float (not good for bar'ing) while the latter is underpinned by long.
2. Your `00:01:00 xbar t` approach almost works, you just need to use timestamps for `t` and `datespan` (aka .z.N, aka type 16, aka "n"$) for the xbar:

```
q)t:"p"$2022.05.23T14:31:04.222 2022.05.23T14:32:04.222;
q)0D00:01:00 xbar t
2022.05.23D14:31:00.000000000 2022.05.23D14:32:00.000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Add 30 seconds; cast to year and minute; sum.

```
q)t
2022.05.23T14:31:04.222

q)f:sum "du"$ ("v"$30)+  / composition

q)f t
2022.05.23D14:31:00.000000000
q)f t+"v"$40
2022.05.23D14:32:00.000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method (this will only round down though):

```
q){`datetime$(`date$x)+`minute$x}2022.05.23T14:31:04.222
2022.05.23T14:31:00.000
```

This should round up & down:

```
q){"z"$("d"$x)+{$[30=`ss$x;00:00:30+;]x}30 xbar"v"$x}2022.05.23T14:31:04.222
2022.05.23T14:31:00.000
q){"z"$("d"$x)+{$[30=`ss$x;00:00:30+;]x}30 xbar"v"$x}2022.05.23T14:31:34.222
2022.05.23T14:32:00.000
```